# How can I solve .settext error in my code?

Tags: android

This is a date picker code to set differences between two dates.

```
long diff = (Edittext1.getTimeInMillis() - Edittext2.getTimeInMillis());
            long edittext = Math.abs(TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
            edittext.setText(edittext+"");
```

Comment: `edittext.setText(...)` – You just defined `edittext` as a `long` in the previous line. You presumably meant to call `setText()` on something else; e.g., some actual `EditText`.

Comment: you haven't declared EditText variable.You are using long type edittext.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set date in edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360915/how-to-set-date-in-edit-text)

Answer (score 0):

declare `editTextView` of type `EditText` and set the text like :

`EditText editTextView = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);` // edit_text is widget's id in xml layout

`editTextView.setText(String.valueOf(edittext));` // edittext is long type value to be set